# werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/home/ubuntu/project_rehearsal/flask2/' with values ['filename']. Did you mean

Tags: html, flask

I am trying to build a web page with flask that upload videos from the user then display it but the problem is the video never plays at the page and in the terminal window showing me the Error
((werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/home/ubuntu/project_rehearsal/flask2/' with values ['filename']. Did you mean 'upload_image' instead?))

This is my Flask file:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,flash,url_for
import pysrt
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
import os
import urllib3.request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/ubuntu/project_rehearsal/flask2/uploads/'
app.config['VIDEO_UPLOADS'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['ALLOWED_VIDEOS_EXTENSIONS'] = "MP4"
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

def allowed_videos(filename):

if not "." in filename:
    return False
ext = filename.rsplit(".",1)[1]
if ext.upper == app.config['ALLOWED_VIDEOS_EXTENSIONS']:
    return True
else:
    return ext.upper

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def display_video(filename):
    print('display_video filename: ' + filename)
    return render_template(url_for('/home/ubuntu/project_rehearsal/flask2/',filename='uploads/' + filename), code=301)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_video():
   if request.method == "POST":
       if request.files:

           video = request.files["video"]
           if video.filename ==  "":
                return redirect(request.url)
           if not allowed_videos(video.filename):
                 print("failed")
                 return redirect(request.url)
           filename = secure_filename(video.filename)

           video.save(os.path.join(app.config['VIDEO_UPLOADS'] ,filename))
           return render_template("video.html",filename=filename)
   return render_template("video.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

And this is my video.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <title>
         upload_file
       </title>
    </head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">

             <h1>Upload an image</h1>
              <hr>
                <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Select image</label>
                     <div class="custom-file">
                         <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="video" id="video">
                         <label class="custom-file-label" for="video">Select video...</label>
                     </div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>

              </form>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         {% if filename %}
         <div style="margin: 10px auto;">
             <video autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" preload="preload">
                 <source src="{{ url_for('display_video', filename=filename) }}" type="video/mp4"></source>
             </video>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`url_for()` is looking for a reference to a view function's name in Flask (for example, `display_video`), and I think you're passing it a absolute filepath on your system.

To fix your error, you can just change your `/uploads/<filename>` endpoint to render your `video.html` html template (no need for `url_for()`) and it should fix that error and show the player on the page under the upload form:

```
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def display_video(filename):
    print('display_video filename: ' + filename)
    return render_template('video.html', filename='uploads/' + filename)
```